# How to multiply a double and an int and cast to int in single statment

Tags: java

I'm trying to accomplish the following without any luck

```
int a = 1;
double b = 0.5;

int myInteger = (int) a*b;
```

Comment: Try printing `b` to the console

Comment: You need to follow what it says. There no trick to this other than not doing something which it didn't ask for. It asked for a `double` and an `int`

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `b` as an integer.

Try this:

```
int a = 1;
double b = 0.5d;
int myInteger = a*b;
```

Comment: The `d` suffix is, of course, optional as double is the [default floating point literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Comment: Yes, totally optional. Force of habit for my own preferred style.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code right? you have two int primitives and no double. With the way you have written it, the b variable will be truncated to 0, as everything after the decimal will be discarded.

I'm guessing this is what you want. Use parens to force the multiplication then cast. Without the parens around a*b the compiler will throw a warning/error due to the loss of accuracy caused by truncation.

```
int a = 2;
double b = 2.5;

int result = (int) (a*b);
System.out.println(result);
```

gives 5 as result.